# Which GRANTS are necessary to SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer works?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to use the code below to do bulkinsert, I have several varchar fields, an Identity and some datetime, int and float fields

```
using DataTable test = logs.ConvertToDataTable();
using SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)_connectionFactory.GetDatabaseConnection();
SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, null);
bulk.DestinationTableName = "[database].[schema].[Table_With_Underline]";
connection.Open();
bulk.WriteToServer(test);
```

I'm getting on the last line the error

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to obtain column collation information for the destination table. If the table is not in the current database the name must be qualified using the database name (e.g. [mydb]..[mytable](e.g. [mydb]..[mytable]); this also applies to temporary-tables (e.g. #mytable would be specified as tempdb..#mytable)`

Tried to rename the table to be without underlines. And if I try to access an unexistent table I get other error
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access destination table '[database].[schema].[Table_With_Underline]'.'`

I don't know what to do, is possible to be about grants on the database?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845412/sqlbulkcopy-failed-to-obtain-column-collation-information-for-the-destination-ta

Comment: I would also make note of the missing brackets for the using statements........so things are going out of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulk operations require specific permission.

Take a look at the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#security

```
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [login]
```

Comment: It was nice seeing the reason at documentation. It allowed me to follow another approach that doesn't require specific permission, since it's an user that I can't change. I ended using the table-value parameter, it needed an User-Defined-Type but that I can create ^_^